# Printing a Triangle

Tags: java, methods

I am having trouble printing a triangle. Using 2 loop statements in the printTriangle method, I have to make a triangle that looks like this.
If user entered 3

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

Using 2 loops in the triangle method that must use the printLine method to print this triangle. I cannot print anything at all in the triangle method and cannot change anything in the line method. Any help with a small explanation would be awesome, thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {

    //Global declaration of the keyboard
        public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int triSize = 0;

        System.out.println("What size triangle would you like to be printed?");
        triSize = kbd.nextInt();

        printTriangle(triSize);
    }

    /**
     * printLine is used to calculate how many asterisks should be printed
     * @param astNum the number given by the user
     * @param x is used to count the number of asterisks that have not and need to be printed
     */
    public static void printLine(int astNum){
        int x;
        for (x = 0;astNum > x; x++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

            System.out.println("");
    }


    public static void printTriangle(int triSize){
         int x = 0;
         for (int i=1; i<=triSize; i++) {
            printLine(triSize);
          }

    }
}
```

Comment: ignore anything in the printTri method right now i was just trying to figure something out but could not.

Answer (score 0):

Add these loops:

```
for (int i=1; i<=triSize; i++) {
            printLine(i);
          }
for (int i=triSize; i>=1; i--) {
            printLine(i);
          }
```

Comment: What size triangle would you like to be printed?
3
***
***
***

Comment: This was what was printed but the lines were going from top to bottom not left to right

Comment: You want `printLine(i);`, not `printLine(triSize)'.  In both loops.

Comment: Of course. I assumed that the first loop that already was there printed the first half correctly. My bad completely. Well, ok, not completely. It would have been avoided if SamMench gave an output example. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using two loops in the `printTriangle()` method to generate the output is exactly how I would approach this problem.  The first loop can print from `1` star to `N` stars, where `N` is the size of the triangle.  Then, use a second loop to print the other half of the triangle.  This is really an exercise in your ability to articulate clean loop boundary conditions in both loops.

```
public static void printTriangle(int triSize) {
    // print stars from 1 to triSize, top to bottom
    for (int i=1; i <= triSize; ++i) {
        printLine(i);
    }
    // print starts from triSize-1 to 1, from top to bottom
    // note carefully that the loop counter here begins at triSize - 1
    for (int i=triSize-1; i >= 1; --i) {
        printLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! I hate to bother u and ask for one more thing but why exactly is this working?

Comment: @SamMench I'm assuming it's obvious to you why the first loop is working.  The trick is in phrasing the conditions of the second loop to count _down_ from `triSize-1` to `1`, printing out stars from top to bottom in reverse order.  That is all there is to it.